# performance issue LibGdx Box2d

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

i have a performance issue while i update/render bodies(Mobs) as you can see from the photo bellow as many bodies i add the memory(private working set) CPU increased for example if i add 100 bodies move random in the map the merory(private working set) will reach 900.000k what is going on? what i am doing wrong?
IMAGE URL : http://prntscr.com/7l31tn

[image]

Mob initialization ->>

```
private void initializeEntityIntoWorld() {

      //initializeTheMOb
      BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
      FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
      PolygonShape boxShape = new PolygonShape();

      bodyDef.position.set(6,3);
      bodyDef.type=BodyType.DynamicBody;
      bodyDef.fixedRotation=true;
      body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
      body.setUserData(this);


      boxShape.setAsBox(WIDTH_METER, HEIGHT_METER);
      fixtureDef.shape=boxShape;
      fixtureDef.filter.categoryBits = Constants.BIT_PLAYER;
      fixtureDef.filter.maskBits = Constants.BIT_GROUND;
      fixtureDef.density = 1;
      fixtureDef.friction = 0f;
      body.createFixture(fixtureDef).setUserData("Mob");

      body.setGravityScale(0);


      boxShape.dispose();

}



@Override
public void update(float deltatime) {
    super.update(deltatime);





}
@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {
    super.render(batch);

    Sprite sprite = new Sprite(currentFrame);
    sprite.setSize(WIDTH_METER*2,HEIGHT_METER*2);
    sprite.setOrigin(sprite.getWidth()/2, sprite.getHeight()/2);


    sprite.setRotation(body.getAngle() * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees);
    sprite.setPosition(body.getPosition().x-sprite.getOriginX(), body.getPosition().y-sprite.getOriginY());
    sprite.draw(batch);



}
```

Level class Update/Render All The bodies

```
    public void render(SpriteBatch batch){

     for (Entity entity : dynamicEntitysDestroyed) 
         world.destroyBody(entity.getBody());
    dynamicEntitysDestroyed.clear();

    for(int i=0;i<dynamicEntitys.size;i++) dynamicEntitys.get(i).render(batch);

}
public void update(float deltatime){

    for(int i=0;i<dynamicEntitys.size;i++){
        Entity entity=dynamicEntitys.get(i);
        if(entity.isRemoved()) 
            dynamicEntitys.removeIndex(i);
        else entity.update(deltatime);
    }

}
public void addEntity(Entity entity){
    dynamicEntitys.add(entity);
}
public void destroyEntity(Entity entity) {
    dynamicEntitysDestroyed.add(entity);

}
```